# A makefile can handle multiple output

Tags: c++, makefile

For example I have something like:

```
SRC = a.cpp b.cpp
INC = somedir/inc anotherdir/inc
OBJ = a.o b.o
```

How can I have the makefile build every obj automatically in one rule instead of one each rule

Comment: `myexe: $(OBJ)`, and then run `make myexe`?

Comment: I mean compile the obj, not linking the objs to get the executable.

Comment: That will build the object files as well as linking them into the executable. If you only want to build a specific object file, then use the command `make a.o`.

Comment: And what is your actual problem? Why do you want to only build the object files but not link them?

Comment: I want to know if it’s possible to modify the file list var only when files are changed(add a new source file for example), instead of add a new rule alongside

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Examples.html#Pattern-Examples

```
%.o : %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

See comment from "some programmer dude" ... he is absolutly right ...

Comment: That rule basically is repeating the existing implicit rule that already exists (except that it's `CXXFLAGS` for the C++ compiler flags, `CXX` for the C++ compiler, and `CFLAGS` shouldn't be used when building C++ source files).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming GNU make, there will be an implicit rule that make every object file dependent on the corresponding source file. This implicit rule will build the object file from the source file.

Unless you need to specify dependencies on header files, a very simple makefile could look just like this:

```
OBJS = a.o b.o

myexe: ${OBJS}
```

That's it. It will make sure that the object files are build before linking them into the `myexe` program.

To add new "source" files, you can just add the corresponding object file to the `OBJS` variable. For example if you also want to build with `c.cpp` then change it to:

```
OBJS = a.o b.o c.o
```

Leave the `myexe` target as it is.